# Optimize query for two many-to-many relationships using the same link table

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I have three entities User, Tenant and Team. There is a many-to-many relationship between User and Tenant, and User and Team. I have a single table UserTenant which covers both of these relations. The logic is that each user is assigned to a team per tenant. The team is a mandatory field. Here are the models.

```cs
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tenant> Tenants {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserTenant> UserTenants { get; set; }
}

public class Tenant
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserTenant> UserTenants { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserTenant> UserTenants { get; set; }
}

public class UserTenant
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TenantId))]
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TeamId))]
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

I have established many-to-many relationships for User<->Tenant and User<->Team using the following configuration which works fine.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasQueryFilter(m => m.TenantId == _tenantId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserTenant>().HasQueryFilter(m => _tenantId == Guid.Empty || m.TenantId == _tenantId);
}

public class UserEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(u => u.Tenants)
            .WithMany()
            .UsingEntity<UserTenant>();

        builder.HasMany(u => u.Teams)
            .WithMany()
            .UsingEntity<UserTenant>();
    }
}
```

However, when I run a query to include both Tenant and Team the SQL generated includes two joins to the relation table UserTenant to get information about Tenants and Teams. **Is there a way to make EF generate a query that uses a single join with user_tenant table to get both Tenant and Team?**

Current linq query and the generated SQL:

```cs
var query = _dbContext.Users
            .Include(x => x.Tenants)
            .Include(x => x.Teams);

var sqlString = query.ToQueryString();
```

The thing to note in the following query (generated by EF core) is the two left joins to user_tenants table. First join gets Tenants for a user and the second join gets Teams for the same user.

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.access_failed_count, a.concurrency_stamp, a.email, a.email_confirmed, a.lockout_enabled, a.lockout_end, a.name, a.normalized_email, a.normalized_user_name, a.password_hash, a.phone_number, a.phone_number_confirmed, a.security_stamp, a.two_factor_enabled, a.user_name, t1.id, t1.archived_on, t1.created_on, t1.is_archived, t1.modified_on, t1.team_id, t1.tenant_id, t1.user_id, t1.id0, t1.created_on0, t1.modified_on0, t1.name, t1.system_generated, t1.tenant_id0, t2.id, t2.archived_on, t2.created_on, t2.is_archived, t2.modified_on, t2.team_id, t2.tenant_id, t2.user_id, t2.id0, t2.account_setting_id, t2.address_line1, t2.address_line2, t2.city, t2.country, t2.created_on0, t2.modified_on0, t2.name, t2.owner_id, t2.postal_code
FROM asp_net_users AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT u.id, u.archived_on, u.created_on, u.is_archived, u.modified_on, u.team_id, u.tenant_id, u.user_id, t0.id AS id0, t0.created_on AS created_on0, t0.modified_on AS modified_on0, t0.name, t0.system_generated, t0.tenant_id AS tenant_id0
    FROM user_tenants AS u
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT t.id, t.created_on, t.modified_on, t.name, t.system_generated, t.tenant_id
        FROM teams AS t
        WHERE t.tenant_id = @__ef_filter___tenantId_2
    ) AS t0 ON u.team_id = t0.id
    WHERE @__ef_filter__p_0 OR u.tenant_id = @__ef_filter___tenantId_1
) AS t1 ON a.id = t1.user_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT u0.id, u0.archived_on, u0.created_on, u0.is_archived, u0.modified_on, u0.team_id, u0.tenant_id, u0.user_id, t3.id AS id0, t3.account_setting_id, t3.address_line1, t3.address_line2, t3.city, t3.country, t3.created_on AS created_on0, t3.modified_on AS modified_on0, t3.name, t3.owner_id, t3.postal_code
    FROM user_tenants AS u0
    INNER JOIN tenants AS t3 ON u0.tenant_id = t3.id
    WHERE @__ef_filter__p_0 OR u0.tenant_id = @__ef_filter___tenantId_1
) AS t2 ON a.id = t2.user_id
ORDER BY a.id, t1.id, t1.id0, t2.id
```

Comment: So, where is your LINQ query?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have added the query and I see that my example had some errors which should be fixed now.

Comment: LINQ query is not same as SQL, probably you have defined Global Query filters?

Comment: You are right, I have added that in the configuration. The "Team" entity has a global TenantId filter.

Comment: You have two many-to-many relationships so it makes sense that you would have two joins. I don't see why you have a concern here.

Comment: Strange that you have defined `UserTenants` collection for entities. `Tenant` should have `Users`,  `Team` also should have `Users`, why it is connected to `UserTenant` is also question.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Users are global and can be added to multiple tenants. They can also be removed from Tenants. So it does not make sense to start with a Tenant and create users from there. When a user is invited to another Tenant, it does not create a new user account, the process just associates another tenant to that user. The team comes in to the picture because in each Tenant a user has to be part of a team. So a tenant assignment also assigns a team hence `UserTenant` table links both `TenantId` and `TeamId` to `userId`.

Comment: @topsail from the SQL perspective it does not make sense to have two separate joins to the same table to get to two separate fields in the same table. The query plan is definitely different between two joins vs a single join.

Comment: I can tell you that far from "not making sense", it is a completely normal query strategy to write SQL queries that can join to the same table twice. Your blanket statement here is just factually incorrect. Be that as it may, an obvious way to show its possible would be to write a sample SQL that would fetch your desired results with only one join. Your question would benefit if you could post some sample data that would illustrate your problem. I personally find it interesting but it needs some test data in order for others to work on this problem.

Comment: @topsail You misunderstood what I meant. It is not a blanket statement. It is a very specific scenario I am describing here. If there is a linking table that has two properties (Tenant and Team in my example) mapping to the same foreign key (UserId in this case), why would you do two joins to get them individually?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood you. Your statement sounded very generalized. But as I said - provide some sample data and show the single join SQL that you think is better than this SQL.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting more with Entity Framework Core 6 I learned how Include works and made me realize what my original query was doing. `Include` essentially will generate a join with the corresponding entity table (through its linking table if needed). So in my case since I had two `Include` to the navigation properties, it produced two joins.

So `.Include(x => x.Tenants)` will create a join block with UserTenants and then a join with Tenants..

Then `.Include(x => x.Teams` will create another join without considering that we already are joining with UserTenants.

Based on this knowledge I tried the following which solved my issue and now I only get one join with UserTenants.

```cs
var query = _dbContext.Users
            .Include(x => x.UserTenants)
              .ThenInclude(ut => ut.Team)
              .ThenInclude(t => t.Tenant);

var sqlString = query.ToQueryString();
```

This produces the following SQL query

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.access_failed_count, a.concurrency_stamp, a.email, a.email_confirmed, a.lockout_enabled, a.lockout_end, a.name, a.normalized_email, a.normalized_user_name, a.password_hash, a.phone_number, a.phone_number_confirmed, a.security_stamp, a.two_factor_enabled, a.user_name, t2.id, t2.archived_on, t2.created_on, t2.is_archived, t2.modified_on, t2.team_id, t2.tenant_id, t2.user_id, t2.id0, t2.created_on0, t2.modified_on0, t2.name, t2.system_generated, t2.tenant_id0, t2.id1, t2.account_setting_id, t2.address_line1, t2.address_line2, t2.city, t2.country, t2.created_on1, t2.modified_on1, t2.name0, t2.owner_id, t2.postal_code
FROM asp_net_users AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT u.id, u.archived_on, u.created_on, u.is_archived, u.modified_on, u.team_id, u.tenant_id, u.user_id, t0.id AS id0, t0.created_on AS created_on0, t0.modified_on AS modified_on0, t0.name, t0.system_generated, t0.tenant_id AS tenant_id0, t1.id AS id1, t1.account_setting_id, t1.address_line1, t1.address_line2, t1.city, t1.country, t1.created_on AS created_on1, t1.modified_on AS modified_on1, t1.name AS name0, t1.owner_id, t1.postal_code
    FROM user_tenants AS u
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT t.id, t.created_on, t.modified_on, t.name, t.system_generated, t.tenant_id
        FROM teams AS t
        WHERE t.tenant_id = @__ef_filter___tenantId_2
    ) AS t0 ON u.team_id = t0.id
    INNER JOIN tenants AS t1 ON t0.tenant_id = t1.id
    WHERE @__ef_filter__p_0 OR u.tenant_id = @__ef_filter___tenantId_1
) AS t2 ON a.id = t2.user_id
ORDER BY a.id, t2.id, t2.id0
```